# Как изменить datapicker в firefox?

Tags: html, html5, веб-программирование, firefox

Можно ли изменить `datepicker` в `html5`? Проблема в `firefox` на планшете, там нельзя изменить год вручную и приходится листать календарь, что очень долго. Можно ли это как-нибудь исправить?

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, нет. Для ваших целей подойдет кастомный `datepicker` от `Bootstrap`. Для него есть куча шаблонов, а можете и сами сверстать необходимый вам дизайн. К примеру, я недавно делал такой календарь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]